# Changing page in stateProvider not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, satellizer

I'm using angular with ui-router and satellizer to check weather user is logged in or not.
Here is my example code:

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', ['satellizer', 'ui.router']);
    App.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/blank');
        $stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    url: '/app',
                    abstract: true,
                    template: 'View<br><div ui-view=""></div>',
                    resolve: {
                        authorize: ['authService', function (authService) {
                            return authService.isLoggedin();
                        }]
                    }
                })
                .state('app.blank', {
                    url: '/blank',
                    title: 'Blank',
                    template: '<div>blank</div>'
                })
                .state('page', {
                    url: '/page',
                    template: 'Page<br><div ui-view=""></div>'
                })
                .state('page.login', {
                    url: '/login',
                    title: "Login",
                    template: 'Login'
                });
    });
    App.factory('authService', function ($rootScope, $state, $auth) {
                return {
                    isLoggedin: function () {
                        if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                            console.log('not logged in');
                            $state.go('page/login');
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
    );
```

In $stateProvider I use resolve to check wheather user is logged in or not. If not script  should move to state page/login but it doesn't - it simply stops working. How to fix that code?

Comment: If I use `$location.path("page/login")` insead of `$state.go("page.login")` it works but why not with `$state.go` which is preffered by ui-router??

Comment: Have you tried $state.go('page.login')?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$state.go('page.login');` instead of `$state.go('page/login');` (Notice the dot!)

You should change to the state name and not to the url of the state.

Answer (score 0):

If the $state doesn't work. Check if $injector work and change the $state to $injector, like this:

```
App.factory('authService', function ($rootScope, $injector, $auth) {
            return {
                isLoggedin: function () {
                    if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                        console.log('not logged in');
                        $injector.get('$state').go('page.login');
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```